# Studio One: Map mixer faders to MIDI CC

Tags: midi, daw

Is it possible in Studio One to map multiple mixer channel volume faders to different MIDI CC messages, e.g. from an external fader controller?

Example:

- CC 102 -> channel 1 volume
- CC 103 -> channel 2 volume

It's possible to create entries for different CCs in the External Devices window using the MIDI learn function (global focus). However, in the mixer, mapping only seems to work for a single channel, not multiple ones.

Note: I do not want to use the Mackie control protocol for the external device.

Answer (score 0):

Easily done, although somewhat unintuitive:

- Assign CCs using MIDI learn function (as described above)
- **Move physical knob or fader you want to assign (this was the part I missed)**
- Right-click mixer fader and select Assign from the drop-down menu